# text is not displaying properly on applet

Tags: java, fonts, applet, mouselistener

I have a program that have to display string on applet window and that string font size must be increased by 2 while mouse is clicked but the problem is that the the string font size is increasing but not showing constantly(static) it showing dynamically 
here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

/*<applet code="fo.class" height=500 width=500></applet>*/
public class fo extends Applet {
    String msg = "";
    int size = 14;
    Font f;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        f = new Font("Rockwell", Font.BOLD, size);
        msg = "GAMER";
        setFont(f);
        g.drawString(msg, 10, 100);
    }

    public void init() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                size = size + 2;
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and also tell me why we have to use (String) in JApplet instead of String while performing any item event in JTextField like this :

```
public void(ItemEvent e){
String s=(String)e.getItem()
setText(""+s);
}
```

why this (String) instead of

```
String s=e.getItem()
```

why we have to use that (String) in that statement because without that (String) program not compiling... tell me What does that (String) mean...??

Answer (score 0):

Set the Font for whole.
instead of using

```
setFont(f);
```

use the following

```
g.setFont(new Font("Rockwell",Font.BOLD,size));
```

you need to use (String) because getItem() returns object, and you need to typecast it to String.